# Is it possible to describe something with a question?

Tags: questions

On the of chance this being possible examples please.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no reason you can't be descriptive in your phrasing of a question. After all, a question is simply a statement turned into an interrogatory either by one or another convention of English. Isn't it?

One of the most famous examples is, of course, Shakespeare's rhetorical question that begins Sonnet 18:

> "Shall I compare thee to a summer's
>   day?"

More declarative descriptions follow, but that line puts an image in the mind of the reader.

Comment: +1 for "isn't it?" That's the enduring classic.

Answer (score 8):

> Isn't it the most incredible/ugly/shiny/repulsive/other-adjective thing you have ever seen?

Ok, clutching at straws here... :)

I should say that you could describe something *while* asking a question, but you would not usually describe something *by* asking a question.